# Running QGIS processing tools in the OSGEO4W shell using the qgis_process functionality, syntax errors

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, osgeo4w

I am trying to run QGIS processing tools in the OSGEO4W shell using the qgis_process functionality. I believe this functionality is fairly new as I have been having a hard time finding documentation for the syntax.

I am trying to run a raster calculator command using two tiffs as input, everything about the command runs fine except for the LAYERS parameter always returns an error as I am not sure how to list two layers in the parameter.

the command is:

```
qgis_process run qgis:rastercalculator --CELLSIZE=0 --CRS="ESPG:32610" --EXPRESSION=""octclip@1" + "marclip@1"" --EXTENT="D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif" --LAYERS=D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif --OUTPUT="D:/UPCD/clip1/try1.tif"
```

I have tried many things such as

```
--LAYERS=D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif

--LAYERS="D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif" "D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif"

--LAYERS="D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif","D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif"

--LAYERS="D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif":"D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif"
```

to no avail.

The documentation says it will allow paths both in quotes as well as without but I can not find anything regarding passing two paths to the parameter argument.

First time question poster, let me know if there is any information I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

I have attempted to run `saga:rasterstatisticsforpolygons` with multiple inputs through the `qgisprocess` R package and have run into the same problem.

```
raster.A <- "D:/file_A.tif"
raster.B <- "D:/file_B.tif"
multilayer <- "VRT_AandB.vrt"
grids_attempt.1 <- paste(raster.A,raster.B,sep = ';')
grids_attempt.2 <- paste(raster.A,raster.B,sep = ',')
grids_attempt.3 <- paste(raster.A,raster.B,sep = ' ')
InputPolygons <-"D:/ZonesForZonalStats.gpkg"
result = "D:/ZonalStatsAdded.gpkg"
```

*`grids_attempt.x`* represents my three attempts to find a syntax that works. I additionally attempted to use a virtual raster as input (*multilayer* above). I did not attempt to use a multiband raster because SAGA does not accept multiband inputs.

```
qgis_run_algorithm(
"saga:rasterstatisticsforpolygons",
GRIDS = grids_attempt.x,  
POLYGONS = InputPolygons,
METHOD =1,
NAMING =0, 
COUNT =0,
MIN =0,
MAX =0,
RANGE =1,
SUM =0,
MEAN =1,
VAR =0,
STDDEV =1,
QUANTILE =0,
RESULT = result,
.quiet = FALSE
)
```

I also attempted multiple syntax guesses in the OSGEO4W shell including a Python list.

```
    qgis_process-qgis run saga:rasterstatisticsforpolygons --GRIDS="['D:/file_A.tif','D:/file_B.tif']" --POLYGONS=D:/ZonesForZonalStats.gpkg --RESULT=D:/ZonalStatsAdded.gpkg --METHOD=1 --NAMING=0 --RANGE=1 --MEAN=1 --STDDEV=1
```

My current understanding is that multilayer input functionality is not available due to a bug in QGIS:

> Ok -- this is a QGIS bug. There's no way to specify a list of layers from a string value alone.
> [How to specify multilayer input? #25](https://github.com/paleolimbot/qgisprocess/issues/25)

Answer (score 1):

The way to specify multilayer arguments:

- with shell command `qgis_process`, repeat the argument multiple times:

```bash
--LAYERS=D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif --LAYERS=D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif
```

- with `qgisprocess::qgis_run_algorithm()` in R, provide the multilayer argument as:

```r
LAYERS = qgis_list_input("D:/UPCD/clip1/octclip.tif", "D:/UPCD/clip1/marclip.tif")
```